# How to Add a New Scheduler in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, hadoop-plugins

I'm trying to add a new scheduler in Hadoop. Its not the default ones (FairScheduler/CapacityScheduler). I checked out the source with svn. Now, **which source file/class should I edit to get this functionality?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend the class `TaskScheduler` in order to write your own scheduler. Once done, you can plug it in your code via the JobTracker property `mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler`. You can find TaskScheduler inside `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`.

HTH

Comment: I think Jar of the created scheduler is needed.... I have my scheduler code but dont know how to create jar of this scheduler and where to put in hadoop source folder(o.20.0 version). Can you help me with this

Comment: This answer is for Hadoop 1. For Hadoop 2 and newer, you need to customize org.apache.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.